# deleting multiple items from listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to delete several items from my listview but it just deletes one element(even though i select more than one). The listview implements `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` which has `delListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`. I have a button where in the onClick method i would first like to check if there are no items selected if so prompt the user with some message. Else if there are some items selected delete them. This is what i have so far:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            selectItems();
            Intent intent = new Intent(); ...
        }
```

selectItems function:

```
private boolean selectItem() 
{
    String message = "Please select an item!";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if(array.valueAt(i))
        {
            String item = delListView.getAdapter().getItem(array.keyAt(i)).toString();
            Log.i("my_app", item + " selected");
            deleteAdapter.remove(item);
            deleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false; //item found
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return true; //no item found
}
```

Thank you for your help!

---

I have managed to solve my problem. My solution was:

```
private void deleteItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i = (array.size()) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(array.valueAt(i))
        {
            String selected = deleteAdapter.getItem(array.keyAt(i));
            Log.i("my_app", selected + " will be selected");
            deleteAdapter.remove(selectat);
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(BUNDLE_DELETE, deleteList);

    setResult(REQUEST_CODE_DELETE_STRING, intent);
    getInstance().finish();

}
private boolean selectItem() 
{
    String message = "Please select an item!";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if(array.valueAt(i))
        {
            String item = delListView.getAdapter().getItem(array.keyAt(i)).toString();
            Log.i("my_app", item + " selected");
            deleteItems();
            return false;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return true; 
}
```

I made a separate method for selecting the items and deleting them. Then i simply called the delete method in the `selectItem()`. In the onClick method i called the `selectItem()` method. 
Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Notifydata set changed after all your items have been removed from the data map.

Answer (score 0):

1) In onClick() call ListView.getCheckedItemPositions() to get the positions of the selected items in the list or ListView. getCheckedItemIds() to get the Id's of the selected items.

2) Then delete them.

3) Then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the Adapter to cause the list to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

see an example :(Portuguese Link) http://nglauber.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/listview-com-selecao-multipla-actionbar.html

```
private boolean selectItem() {

    String item = delListView.getAdapter().getItem(array.keyAt(i)).toString();

    SparseBooleanArray checked =  listView.getCheckedItemPositions();  

    for (int i = checked.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {  
        if (checked.valueAt(i)) {  

           String item = delListView.getAdapter().getItem(checked.valueAt(i)).toString();
           deleteAdapter.remove(item);  
        }  
    } 

    deleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true; //no item found
}
```

Edited:

> I first want to verify(when
>   pressing a button) if there are no items selected.

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick( final View v ) {

        SparseBooleanArray checked =  listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        if ( checked.size() == 0 ) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: This code just deletes the selected item. I first want to verify(when pressing a button) if there are no items selected. If there`s no item selected display a toast or a dialogbox to the user saying that he must select an item in order to continue.

Comment: @user3775739, I edited my answer, you can check if there are any items selected by checking the size of SparseBooleanArray!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me!! In the meantime i managed to solve my problem, see my original post.